# 2 boolean check aren't compatible

Tags: java, boolean-operations

Trying to create a method that will make an array and assign different numbers from 1 - 9 to each index of the array (nos. cannot be repeated).
please have a look at the boolean comparison i made, this is where the cmd stuck at runtime. I have tried to separate the two but nothing happens.

Please help.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Testing {

public static void main (String[] args) {

  ArrayList<Integer> grid = new ArrayList<Integer>();

     int randNum;
     int count = 0;
     int size=8;

     for (int b = 0; b <=size; b++) { 

       while (count <= size) {

        randNum = (int) (Math.random() * 9);


           if (grid.contains(randNum) == false & randNum != 0 ) { 

            grid.add(randNum);
            count++;

          }
       }
     System.out.println(grid.get(b)); 
    }
   System.out.println("size: " + grid.size());
  }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the code is getting "stuck?" Seems like it's just terminating without filling the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) instead?

That is, fill the array with 1-9 and then `Collections.shuffle()` it.

---

Aside: use `&&` not `&` in your original code.

Comment: but what bothers me is, why 2 logical expressions cant be used in one "if ()"?

     if (grid.contains(randNum) == false && randNum != 0 )

     please tell me if this is logically wrong, based on my code.

Comment: the same thing when i removed randNum !=0

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Matt Ball, create an array 1-9 and shuffle, but to answer your question, the problem is here:

```
randNum = (int) (Math.random() * 9);
if (grid.contains(randNum) == false & randNum != 0 ) {
```

Should be this:

```
randNum = (int) (Math.random() * 9) + 1;
if (grid.contains(randNum) == false) {
```

since you multiply `Math.random() * 9` you will only get numbers between `0-8`, adding 1 will give you `1-9`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong or unknowingly actually at several places:

1. & and && are two different things. Use && when you want to continue to check for second condition iff  first operand or condition evaluates to true otherwise to evaluate both operands use &.
2. Why multiplying by 9. Multiply it by 10. As multiply by 9 constrained to 1-8  numbers only.
3. Why are you printing the grid within a loop and having a special loop for same?. Just print the grid it will show you all the elements.

Below is your corrected program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        ArrayList<Integer> grid = new ArrayList<Integer>();

     int randNum;
     int count = 0;
     int size=8;

       while (count <= size) {
        randNum = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        System.out.println(randNum+"test"+grid); 
           if (!grid.contains(randNum) && randNum != 0 ) { 
               System.out.println("grid coming in here"+grid); 
            grid.add(randNum);
            count++;

          }
       }
     System.out.println(grid); 
   System.out.println("size: " + grid.size());
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i thought it would generate nos from 0 ~ 9?